# Fast jump to another feature in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, features

I am looking for a method (plugin) to choose the next feature of my vector layer really fast. I need to edit a lot of polygons and fast choosing the next record is really necessary (using an arrow or something similar).

I have found a plugin like go2nextfeature but it works only with QGIS 2. I use QGIS 3.

Do you know any comfortable method (maybe a keyboard shortcut) to do that?

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent of go2nextfeature for QGIS 3 is the plugin named ["Go2NextFeature3"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Go2NextFeature3/#plugin-about).

> Allows jumping from a feature to another following an attribute order